# MySQL query limiting each "OR" results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to have a single query where I am doing

```
WHERE blah = bleh 
  AND this = that 
  AND age = 21
```

Where I can limit the "Blah" and the "This" results to like 3 or less each? I know I can tack a `LIMIT X` to the end of the query but the limits total results. For my query I want 3 of this, and 3 of that and three of another.. but no more than 3 per, if each has less or none, oh well. Also is it possible with this idea to still have a max result limit?

Or is this something I would have to do across multiple queries, or something I would have to trim the results server side somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a union accomplishes what you need.

```
(select * from table where A='AValue' limit 3)
  union
(select * from table where B='BValue' limit 3)
  union
(select * from table where C='CValue' limit 3)
```

Comment: Be aware that the LIMIT works in this case because of the brackets

Comment: hmm never tried union before. lets say my query is a little more complex than I stated would I be able to wrap brackets around the given example above so they are all in one central bracket and yield a similar set of results?